# why I am getting undefined when passing an array into a usestate argument (react js)

Tags: reactjs

code : const [Proposals, setProposals] = useState(sequenceProposals);
sequenceProposals is an imported array from other file.
console.log(sequenceProposals) gives me array having 40 objects
console.log(Proposals) gives my undefined. -> why???

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are exporting the data in other file.
e.g.

```
export const sequenceProposals = [{}, {}, ...]
```

And the also check whether you are destructuring that data while importing.
e.g.

```
import {sequenceProposals} from '<file_location>/your_file'
```

This destructured data can be used directly while setting up the state.